# Extra fields in has_many associations in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models. There are Item and Category. They have has_many associations for each other. Join table call categories_items and have no model for it. By default it has item_id, category_id and timestamps.

The goal is to add extra field to this join table. If I just add field to this table by migration how can I access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a join model and defining a

```
has_many :items, through: <model>
```

relationship. See [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) for detailed information.